# continuous function with extreme value thereom

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

two continuous function $f, g :[0,1] \to [0,1]$ satisfies $f \circ g=g \circ f$. Then there exist $x_0 \in [0,1]$ satisfied $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$

Comment: Are you trying to prove this fact? If so, what work have you done? What have you tried?

Comment: I think $range(f)=[a,b],range(g)=[c,d]$ with extreme value theorem, and I want to show a=c, b=d

Comment: Note that there must be a fixed point $x_1$ of $f$. Then $f(g(x_1))=g(f(x_1))=g(x_1)$. Therefore, $g$ sends fixed points of $f$ to fixed points of $f$. Let $x_M$ be the maximum of the fixed points (the set of fixed points is closed in $[0,1]$ and therefore compact) of $f$ and $x_m$ the minimum fixed point of $f$. Then $g(x_m)\geq x_m=f(x_m)$ and $g(x_M)\leq x_M=f(x_M)$. So, there are two points $x_m$ and $x_M$ where $f$ and $g$ are in different order.Applying the intermediate value theorem to $f-g$ in the interval $[x_m,x_M]$ you get the existence of $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)-g(x_0)=0$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Excellent, why not post this as an  answer?